# Export an Oracle database, import it to a different user, stored procedures don't work

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, java-stored-procedures

I export an oracle "schema" using

```
exp userid=/ file=pt.dmp log=pt.log owner=FOO buffer=10000000 statistics=NONE direct=Y
```

and then import it into a different schema on the same oracle instance on the same SID using

```
imp userid=/ file=pt.dmp fromuser=FOO touser=paul
```

When I try to access the stored procedures with the new user, I get

```
ORA-29541: class PAUL.ESMQOracleStoredProc could not be resolved
```

Any idea why one user can resolve this but another one can't?

Comment: This error message indicates a missing or inaccessible JAVA stored procedure.

A quick glance at your command line seems to reveal you are using the right parameters (owner for exp, and fromuser for imp). 

Since the message complains about the target user's object, it is also not a hardcoded, qualified procedure name. The only thing I can think of is that somehow paul does not have the privilege to create java stored procedures, but then you'd notice while using imp I guess..

Comment: @Roland, I made sure that user PAUL was created with "grant create procedure to PAUL", as a matter of fact, I used the same script I used to create FOO.

Comment: In user FOO check to see if any of the stored procedures are not owned by FOO.  Public synonyms can easily produce this effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message indicates that this is a *java* stored procedure.  So it requires java permissions.  The `CREATE PROCEDURE` privilege won't cover it.  For starters FOO will need  `JAVAUSERPRIV` as well, so perhaps this is what PAUL lacks?

In addition, if that JSP does anything esoteric it will require additional privileges granted through `dbms_java.grant_permission()`.  You can find that out by using [the DBA_JAVA_POLICY view](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_2195.htm) to compare granted permissions for PAUL and FOO.

Comment: The DBA tells me that the Java stored procedure compiles under the "FOO" user but not under the "PAUL" user.  Fortunately we've eliminated the need for the Java stored procedure so I haven't pursued it any further.